# Connection between VC++ and MATlab

Tags: matlab, visual-c++

How to send values to Matlab function from VC++ and then receive values (results) from Matlab to VC++ in a loop?

I have main source code in VC++ and I don't want to rewrite my code in matlab or matlab function in c++. But rather calling a matlab function in VC++.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should read about [`mex`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-mex-files.html).

Comment: It is more complicated. Is there any easy way to do that?